# Django Template Takes The Information From The Other One

Tags: django

inside of the views.py

```
def book_detail(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Library, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'book_detail.html', context={'book': book})

def admin_book_detail(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Library, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'admin_book_detail.html', context={'book': book})
```

Hello, I am new to Django. I have two views like this. One of them is for normal user and the other one is for admin. But the template of admin takes it's information from the other one. Like, If I change the book_detail, admin_book_detail changes too. But if i change admin_book_detail's information, nothing happens.

inside of admin_book_detail.html

```
{% block content %}
     {{ block.super }}
    <div style="margin:0 auto;width:1200px;">
        <h1 class="page-header" style="color:black;">{{ book.title }}</h1>

        <h2> This book is <b>{{ book.availability }}</b> to borrow</h2>
        <br>
        <h3>Author of the Book = <b>{{ book.author }}</b></h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Publish Year = <b>{{ book.year }}</b></h3>
        <br>
        <h3> Category = <b>{{ book.category }}</b></h3>
        <div style="padding: 10px 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: white;padding: 10px 30px; width:175px;border: 3px solid black;text-align:center;">
                <a  style="color:black; font-size:19px;" href="{% url 'adminbook' %}"><b>Go Back</b></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

inside of book_detail.html

```
{% block content %}
     {{ block.super }}
    <div style="margin:0 auto;width:1200px;">
        <h1 class="page-header" style="color:black;">{{ book.title }}</h1>

        <h2> This book is <b>{{ book.availability }}</b> to borrow</h2>
        <br>
        <h3>Author of the Book = <b>{{ book.author }}</b></h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Publish Year = <b>{{ book.year }}</b></h3>
        <br>
        <h3> Category = <b>{{ book.category }}</b></h3>
        <div style="padding: 10px 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: white;padding: 10px 30px; width:175px;border: 3px solid black;text-align:center;">
                <a  style="color:black; font-size:19px;" href="{% url 'book' %}"><b>Go Back</b></a>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

inside of the url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('request_book/', request_book, name='request_book'),
    re_path(r'book_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', book_detail, name='book_detail'),
    re_path(r'admin_book_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', admin_book_detail, name='admin_book_detail'),
    path('add_book/', add_book, name='add_book')

]
```

Edit : Ok I fixed it.

Comment: Add any code as **text** not as images, It is easier for people to help you that way.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks. It looks better now.

Comment: Does admin_book_detail.html extend book_detail.html?

Comment: No but they have both urls like       book/book_detail and book/admin_book_detail. I don't know how to do it like book/book_detail and adminbook/admin_book_detail

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that both of your views does the same thing. So it really won't matter whichever view you call.

It's different on the HTML page on basis of how you want to represent that information.

They both access the same object without any specific filter, so they're going to return the same object. If you are looking to display different filtered results, you need to change the query.

Comment: Yes but I want both views do the same thing but direct to the different pages. Because i will add admin and student users later.

Comment: Did you checked the URL, these templates are all similar to me, and URL route is correct as well.

Comment: Yes I did. It shows the url route well. I can get inside admin_book_detail.html but when I go back, it redirects me to the book_details redirect page.